# How can pause / play embed sound in AS3 flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio

I have a sound with a length of 1:30 min. I embedded it into my swf and set it to sync with the frame. I need is to be able to pause and play this sound via ActionScript.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

```
//number that is redefined when the pause button is hit
var pausePoint:Number = 0.00;

//a true or false value that is used to check whether the sound is currently playing
var isPlaying:Boolean;

//think of the soundchannel as a speaker system and the sound as an mp3 player
var soundChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var sound:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("SOUND.mp3"));

//you should set the xstop and xplay values to match the instance names of your stop button and play/pause buttons
xstop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickStop);
xplay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickPlayPause);

soundChannel = sound.play();
isPlaying = true;

function clickPlayPause(evt:MouseEvent) {
    if (isPlaying) {
        pausePoint = soundChannel.position;
        soundChannel.stop();
        isPlaying = false;
    } else {
        soundChannel = sound.play(pausePoint);
        isPlaying = true;
    }
}

function clickStop(evt:MouseEvent) {
    if (isPlaying) {
        soundChannel.stop();
        isPlaying = false;
    }
    pausePoint = 0.00;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just did a test to see it works.

1. I made a MovieClip that just has the sound on the timeline( timeline
   is long enough to hold all the
   sound)
2. I've set the Sync to Stream from the Properties Panel on the layer
   that has the sound. This means that
   the sound will be in sync with the
   frames.
3. I've added two buttons to test controlling the sound, which is just
   controlling the movie clip that
   holds the sound sice it's synched
   with the frames.

Here's the basic code:

```
//playBtn and pauseBtn are two basic buttons
//sound is the movie clip that holds the synched sound in its timeline
playBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound);
pauseBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseSound);

function playSound(event:MouseEvent):void{
    sound.play();
}
function pauseSound(event:MouseEvent):void{
    sound.stop();
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control embedded sound globally, There is a class is AS3 called `SoundMixer`. You can control all sound globally as below code,

```
SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0); //This will mute all sound from SWF.
SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(1); //This will unmute all sound from SWF.
```

But if you want to control individual sounds embedded in `MovieClip`s, above method wont work. In this case, Every `Sprite` and `MovieClip` class has a property called `soundTransform`. You can change `soundTransform` property of objects of `MovieClip` or `Sprite` and control them.

You can also give linkage to `Sound` in library and create sound dynamically. In this way though, syncing couldn't be accomplish.

Comment: Seven and a half years later and your answer just saved me after an hour of research! Thank you!!!